# do_shortcode not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm working on a wordpress site where I wrote the theme from scratch, I use php calls to get the wordpress functionality that I need in certain sections.

I'm trying to use a plugin, but calling it via

```
echo do_shortcode('[STORE-LOCATOR]');
```

just isnt working. Even when I switch to the default template and post that code, it still doesnt work. It simply echoes `"[STORE-LOCATOR]"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode): "If there are no shortcode tags defined, then the content will be returned without any filtering. This might cause issues if a plugin is disabled as its shortcode will still show up in the post or content." - is the plugin really active?

Comment: Does `[STORE-LOCATOR]` works in post content?

Comment: @Pekka yes the plugin is active too

Answer (score 53):

`[STORE-LOCATOR]` is probably not a '*shortcode*' in WordPress sense.

I encountered this on different plugin, Stream media player. They use the same syntax as shortcodes, but they are actually not.

Try using:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content',' [STORE-LOCATOR] ');
```

instead of `do_shortcode`, and see if it helps.

Comment: I just ran into this exact (store locator) problem and found this question. This answer fixed the problem and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: how is this not the accepted answer? This works. I had this issue with an ecommerce plugin!
Thank you!

Comment: You, friend, are a saviour! Thank you!

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for! I was using the Calendar plugin called for shortcode {CALENDAR} but do_shortcode() didn't work.  apply_filters() did. THANKS!

Answer (score 36):

`do_shortcode()` returns a string.
I get it working by doing:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(...); ?>
```

Comment: this is the simple solution after 2 hours i love you

Answer (score 3):

This is specific to the Store Locator plugin, not `do_shortcode` in general.

`apply_filters` can be an acceptable workaround for other plugins, but this does not work for Store Locator; you will only see an empty space and some controls.  This is because it is looking for that shortcode in the page/post body to determine whether or not to include all of its js references at the top of the page.  And without these references, nothing will  work.  See the `sl_head_scripts` function in sl-functions.php.

To change this behavior, simply modify that function to match based upon page title instead.  In my instance I wanted it only on a "shop" page, so I commented out the entire `$on_sl_page` test and replaced it with this:

`$on_sl_page = ( strpos($pagename, 'shop') === 0 );`

I then called it from my page with apply_filters as indicated in the other answer:

`echo apply_filters( 'the_content','[STORE-LOCATOR]');`

And this appears to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo do_shortcode('[STORE-LOCATOR][/STORE-LOCATOR]');
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because of length.  Try explaining your answer in further depth.

Answer (score 0):

Try using shortcode after the WordPress environment has been set up.

```
function my_function() {
   echo do_shortcode('[STORE-LOCATOR]');
}
             
add_action('wp', 'my_function');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're writing the whole thing from scratch, you'll want to make sure that the function you create is in the root php file of your plugin. The function might look something like this, but you'll have to sub in whatever logic you're using to arrive at the store location:

```
<?php
function doCoolStuff () {
$var1 = "value1";
$var2 = "value2";
$output = $var1+$var2;
}
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('SOTRE-LOCATIOR', 'doCoolStuff');
?>
```

Then in your template put the code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[STORE-LOCATOR]');?>
```

Happy coding and good luck!